# How do I send my products in the same wordpress mail?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a wordpress site. On this site I have products. When you click a product a little div appears on the same site stating to input your contact details. 
So far I have gotten wp mail to work. So the inputs send to my mail. However I need to be able add the clicked product to the mail. So basically it will send out an order to me saying the name of the product and the other inputs.
Im a bit confused on how to get this to work.
Any ideas? Ajax maybe?

Comment: get the product id and send it to via ajax. then get the product by id details in ajax function and send email with product details

Comment: in the same contact detail form make a hidden input with the product id and use that to get all the product information

Comment: Case 1:
Why dont you woocommerce? If you use woocommerce it is having a typical ecommerce system, and when while the user hits the place order button you can get it from admin dashboard, as well as you will be notified via email that a new order has been placed!!



Case 2: If you using typical wordpress while you sending the email, get the product info by product ID and attach the product details along with the image(if you want) and attach the details in the email!

Comment: I need to get the product id and put it in the form somehow onclick.